# Having issue with startForPostWithGraphPath

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm really exhausted and couldn't no longer think straight.  There seems to be some problem that for the last 2 days, I no longer can post from my iOS app.  The app is still in development stage.  The api I use is

**[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/my app"
                                       graphObject:action
                                 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)**

An the error I'm getting is follow:

**The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
{
    "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey" = ", expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-08-11 02:50:49 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(\n    \"publish_actions\",\n    \"user_photos\"\n)>";
    "com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 500;
    "com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     (
                {
            body =             {
                error =                 {
                    code = 1;
                    message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
                    type = OAuthException;
                };
            };
            code = 500;
        }
    );
}**

Is there a problem with FB since 2 days ago?

Much appreciated if anyone can shed some light.

Thanks,

BS

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't paste your exact code, but just in case:

Should be:

@"me/myapp_namespace:my_actiontype"

Then see the answer I posted here:

[Error code 5 when publishing Facebook Open-Graph story through iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205050/error-code-5-when-publishing-facebook-open-graph-story-through-ios)