# Error code 5 when publishing Facebook Open-Graph story through iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to publish a FB Opengraph story through xcode and havent been able to do so yet.

The url is a static url, with all the meta tags set in the html file itself.

```
 NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];

  action[@"testaction"] = @"http://myfbapp.com/fbobject.html";

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/myfbapp:publish"
                                           graphObject:action
                                     completionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
}];
```

The code has been taken straight from the facebook app itself.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the action had not been reviewed by FB and was in test mode. The account I was trying to post with was not the developer account linked with the FB App and therefore I was unable to post the action.

Once I logged in with my dev account, it was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling startForPostWithGraphPath,

make sure the session is open:

```
NSLog(@"activeSession isOpen: %d", [[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]);
```

make sure the session has 'publish_actions' permissions:

```
NSLog(@"session perms: %@", [[FBSession activeSession] permissions]);
```

if not,

```
if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
```

then ask for permission:

```
if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
                defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
```